# What other can destroy Activity by the system than app with higher prio need for memory?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Android's Activity life cycle again. I looked at the [official life cycle diagram](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and I got puzzled because it suggests that there may be some other reasons why Android OS will destroy Activity besides the case when other app with higher prio needs memory?

[image]

In the [onDestroy() section](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy) I see there are only 2 reasons:

1. is finishing (after a call to [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()))
2. is being destroyed by Android OS due to configuration change

**The diagram however suggests that there are some other reasons why system may want to destroy this Activity, are there?**

Answer (score 0):

In general, if Android wants to reclaim resources it will kill off the OS process hosting an app that is in the background.

However, we have seen situations where, instead of killing off the entire OS process, Android will selectively destroy activities to reclaim resources. This seems to be manufacturer-dependent and has probably been implemented by specific manufacturers (for whatever reason). In this case, Android will call `onDestroy()` on activities that have had `onStop()` called, even though the `Activity` has not called `finish()`.

We don't know exactly why this occurs but we have definitely seen it. It is possible that this happens when the user removes the app from the recent tasks list (by swiping) and the app has a running `Service` in the OS process. In this case, Android may be just destroying all activities but leaving the OS process running so as not to have to restart the `Service`.